# Install httpd-devel on centos8 -Unable to find a match error

Tags: httpd, centos8

I am trying to install httpd-devel on my centos8 machine and have the following error:

```
[root@localhost tmp]# yum install httpd-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 0:02:01 ago on Mon 22 Aug 2022 11:57:03 AM +04.
No match for argument: httpd-devel
Error: Unable to find a match: httpd-devel
```

Please find below CentOS-Base.repo:

```
CentOS-Base.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the ##mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#

[BaseOS]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=BaseOS&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/BaseOS/$basearch/os/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial
```

Any idea why i am getting the following error message pls:

```
Error: Unable to find a match: httpd-devel
```

I have tried the following command also but get the same error:

```
[root@localhost native]# [root@localhost native]# yum install epel-release
CentOS-8 - Base                                                                                                           5.6 kB/s | 3.9 kB     00:00
CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream                                                                                                 14 kB/s | 3.9 kB     00:00
CentOS Linux 8 - BaseOS                                                                                                    15 kB/s | 3.9 kB     00:00
CentOS Linux 8 - Extras                                                                                                   4.8 kB/s | 1.5 kB     00:00
Docker CE Stable - x86_64                                                                                                  14 kB/s | 3.5 kB     00:00
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                                                                             22 kB/s |  53 kB     00:02
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64                                                                     24 kB/s |  63 kB     00:02
Metadata cache created.
[root@localhost native]# yum install httpd-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:12 ago on Mon 22 Aug 2022 02:26:58 PM +04.
No match for argument: httpd-devel
Error: Unable to find a match: httpd-devel
```

Thanks in advance for advice.

Comment: The reason is most probably that CentOS 8 reached its end of life last year and the AppStream repository that contains the httpd-devel packages does not hold any packages for CentOS 8 anymore. Use a distribution that is still supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CentOS 8 is dead, do not use it. Do not use vault.centos.org to install new things, that is an archive and does not get updates, security or otherwise.

Migrate to RHEL or one of its rebuilds, Alma, Rocky, Oracle. All of which have httpd-devel in appstream repo.

CentOS Stream exists and gets updates if you want "early access" of RHEL, but it is no longer a rebuild. Migrate to Stream only if you have a clear use case for previewing RHEL development.

And finally, this is complicated because modular packages make things maximally confusing. httpd is modular in el8, so refer to [module docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/installing_managing_and_removing_user-space_components/finding-rhel-8-content_using-appstream) for the special dnf commands.

Comment: what about CentOS 7 ? is it also dead? then I will always avoid CentOS ?

Answer (score 2):

By installing popular additional repositories on CentOS 8:

```
yum install epel-release 
yum makecache
yum install httpd-devel
```

Comment: I have tried it but still get the same error, please see question I have updated it.

Comment: use another repository: rpm -ivh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-8.rpm

Comment: Neither epel nor remi repo would provide httpd, due to their polices of not replacing base OS packages.